# Angular timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have made an app with ionic and angularjs. I have 3 pages. When the app goes to page 2, if you stay 20 seconds....the page redirects to the first page.

Now the problem is  the $timeout works only 2 times.

My controller code is:

```
.controller('Step2Ctrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout) {
    //Timeout
    var promise;
    $scope.start = function () {
        $scope.stop();
        promise = $timeout(function () { $state.go('step1'); }, 20000);
    }

    $scope.stop = function () {
        $timeout.cancel(promise);
    };

    $scope.start();

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.stop();
    });

});
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: in your timeout, before `$state.go`, can you log `$scope.$$destroyed`? If it is true you could add a condition `if (!$scope.$$destroyed) { $state.go(...) }`

Comment: As I can see, the problem is, when a page loads the function never fire. I think that the on page load never works

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Ionic has a views cache system, saving the rendered HTML and executing your controllers code only once (see Caching area in this link http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/). This is done because it makes your app faster when a view has already rendered.

To solve this, Ionic provides you with some angular events from UI Router (which Ionic uses for the routes system) to control wich part of your controller's code you want to execute before or after the view has rendered.

So, in your controller add this code and it will always call your start() function when the view enters.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicParentView.beforeEnter',function(){
  $scope.start();
})
```